# html table load php file onclick and send values

Tags: php, jquery, html, html-table

Please may I have your help? I have made a simple html table with text input boxes for my mum's business, I would like to send them in a email, so I have made a PHP script, but it never sends the email. I have many simple forms on my server that work fine but I used html forms so it was very easy. However I cannot work out what is going wrong with code; the php script fires and I get a confirmation message and redirected to my menu but no email. I have simplified my code so it it just has one table row and one dropdown box and two text entry boxes. Please could someone show me the solution to my error? I have a basic knowledge of PHP.

This is the link to my website "its basic" the form I'm stuck with is the rent form, the rest work fine. http://www.edwinswebsite.co.uk/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- 
    edwin martin
    27/06/2016
    V1 
-->
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <!-- ensures the document is using the correct char set --> 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="a quick description of the page goes here">  

  <title>payment form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">

<!-- 
       The below section looks like a comment, but it's a conditional include statement.
       It's ignored by all browsers except IE9.  html5shiv is a library that fixes some HTML5 
       IE bugs. 
-->

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">


  </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
           <h1 class="red">Proof of Payment Form</h1>

           <table> 
            <caption> 
            <select size="1" name="cf_drop_down"  class="drop">
              <option value="  Not selected">Select Address</option>
              <option value="  2 Some rd">2 Some rd</option>
              <option value="  6 Other rd">6 Other rd</option>
              <option value="  7 More rd">7 More rd</option>
              <option value="  19 More rd">19 More rd</option>
              <option value="  38 More  rd">38 More  rd</option>
              <option value="  54 Forth rd">54 Forth rd</option>
              <option value="  72 Fifth ave">72 Fifth ave</option>
              <option value="  77 Fifth ave">77 Fifth ave</option>
              <option value="  99 Fifth ave">99 Fifth ave</option>
            </select>
            </caption>
            <tr>
                <th> Student 1 Name</th>
                <th> Student 2 Name </th>
                <th> Student 3 Name </th>
                <th> Student 4 Name </th>
                <th> Student 5 Name </th>
                <th> Student 6 Name </th>
                <th> Student 7 Name </th>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                 <td><input type="text" value="test"  name="cf_name1"></td>
                 <td><input type="text" value="test"  name="cf_name2"></td>              
                 <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                 <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                 <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                 <td><input type="text" value=""></td>               
                 <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            </tr>


<input type="button" value="Send" class="submit_button" onclick="location.href='payment.php'" method="post">
<input type="button" value="Menu" class="submit_button" onclick="location.href='index.html'">           
        </table>

        </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

PHP code

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name1'];
$field_name2 = $_POST['cf_name2'];


$drop_down_item = $_POST['cf_drop_down'];


$mail_to = 'xxxx@example.com, xxxxx@example.com';
$subject = 'Message from me '.$field_name;


$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_name2."\n";
$body_message .= 'Address: '.$drop_down_item."\n";


$headers = 'From: '.$field_name."\r\n";


$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to xxxx@example.com');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: there's no form tags here

Comment: you also should mark all those questions of yours as solved where answers were given that solved them.

Comment: no i am trying to figure out if it is possible with out a form, is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok for now i simply put a form tag inside the table and my php is working fine